# Accessing a tab bar item without the page

Tags: ios, objective-c, share

I have 4 tab items in my tab bar controller. When I click on the "share" item, the

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

delegate is called. Then a popup comes up. This popup is separate from the "share" *page* itself. I want the popup to show, and not the page.

All help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: `Xcode` has nothing to do with your problem..!!

Comment: This is a project made in Xcode. I think it rather does apply to my problem.

Comment: @doc92606 See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info. Your question is not about Xcode.

Comment: My apologies, thanks for editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control drag your tabbar to your "File's owner" in IB and set it as the delegate.

You can't set a target action to your tab bar items. They should always have a new view. The only way is - you should use delegates which determine that your tabbar item is touched and then handle which tab is pressed in that delegate.

Next drop this code in your viewcontroller.m file.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item

{

      if(item.tag == 1)
      {
      }

}
```

You should set a tag value to your tab bar item from the properties in xcode.

Comment: Thanks for specifying in the beginning :)